# Why am I not seeing what I expect when I use Python 2.7's decimal function?

Tags: python, decimal

I'm just beginning to use Python 2.7 and am trying to build a simple credit payment calculator as a test. From what I've been able to find, the decimal function should force the program to calculate to a specific number of decimal places. From the documentation pages:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 6
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.142857')
>>> getcontext().prec = 28
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
```

So my understanding is if I type the following:

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec=2
total =5
print Decimal(total)
```

I should get the following

> 5.00

However, it keeps printing 5. If I type `Decimal (5)` or `Decimal (total)` I get the output `Decimal ('5')`. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: thanx for the edit Michael it looked really odd the way it was im still trying to find my way around here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why dont you just do format strings?

```
 >>> print "{0:0.2f}".format(5)
 5.00
```

sorry I dont know anything about the decimal package so I really cant help you there...ive never really understood the need, or niche for the decimal package

http://www.shocksolution.com/2011/11/python-string-format-examples/

http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec

Comment: that looks like it would work i dont suppose you would have a link so i can read up more on format strings?

Comment: @Joran: Decimal numbers can be represented exactly.  Especially for financial applications, if you tried using floating point numbers instead of Decimal arithmetic (introduced in Python 2.4) it was a bit of a mess.

Comment: ahh gotcha thanks ... floats are pretty much fine for my stuff I think

Answer (score 3):

The precision you're setting is the *mathematical precision of calculations.* It has nothing to do with the number of decimal places printed. A `Decimal` instance will print the shortest textual representation of itself by default. To print otherwise, use Python string interpolation (`%` operator) or the `format()` method of strings.